# Unique-ness in the languages of Math and Physics?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, physics

### Background

So here's something I was pondering about:

A teacher asks a student: "what is 3+1?"

The student replies "3+1"

It's not that the student's reply is wrong. But it's not an answer that will suffice in a math class. In math and physics I often notice a game being played. Let's say you want to discuss the idea of an electric field. You introduce a notion of a unit test charge and say it is the force that the test charge would experience. Note the same phenomena could be explained by saying we introduce 2 units of charge and the electric field is half the force experienced.

I think both math and physics rely on a notion of uniqueness in their language. And since they have one unique description of a particular phenomena they can map it to other descriptions of the same phenomena. Note this, not always how it plays out. For example quantum mechanics could be described by both linear algebra and differential equations only to have both perspectives unified into a language of bra and ket notation by Dirac.

It seems to me central to this language is the idea of unique-ness. On that note I will ask this question:

### Question

Given different mathematical objects how does one ascertain if they can describe the same phenomenona? (I suspect this is a statement about the mapping between mathematical objects)

Comment: " both math and physics rely on a notion of uniqueness in their language. And since they have one unique description of a particular phenomena they can map it to other descriptions of the same phenomena. " I would say that we have multiple "names"/description of the same phenomenon: we prove (either mathematically or experimentally) that they are different ways to "describe" the unique fact/object.

Comment: This feature is common to natural language: we have [Napoleon Bonaparte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon) which is also known as Napoleon I and as "the First Consul of the French Republic".

Comment: What you are describing is the opposite of uniqueness; it is the existence of multiple names for the same thing. Also, the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DavidGudeman the question is essentially how does one Identitfy if 2 seemingly different mathematical objects can be used to describe the same phenomenona. And suggestions for editting would help?

Comment: This wiki article does a pretty good job of explaining mathematical uniqueness, "the uniqueness of a mathematical object, which usually means that there is only one object fulfilling given properties, or that all objects of a given class are equivalent (i.e., they can be represented by the same model). This is often expressed by saying that the object is uniquely determined by a certain set of data." A useful homonym to *unique* is singularity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_theorem

Comment: This certainly depends on the knowledge and ability of the practitioner of the said field. be it maths or ethics. 3+1 could be viewed as the usual binary addition function in PA, or the summation group operation in the usual Ring R, or even in the closed C or beyond, which is not described by a "unique" mathematical object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort of example you provide is based on the idea of a normal form.

"In a rewriting system, a term is said to be of normal form if it does not admit any further rewrites." [source](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/normal+form)

When we have the expression `3+1` in the context of arithmetic, this is un-normalized. There is a unique normal form, namely the expression `4`. Roughly this means that there is a decidable algorithm which uniquely reduces every possible expression to a sub-set of possible expressions. We can think of this as a species of equality where the equality of two mathematical expressions can be established through purely syntactical manipulation. In type theory this can be called judgmental equality or computational equality.   It is contrasted with propositional equality. In mathematical contexts where expressions do not always converge to a normal form, you can establish propositional equality via additional axioms. For example, in ZF set theory the axiom of extensionality says that sets are equal if they have equal members.